# jasper is not working in jar file

Tags: java, filesystems, jasper-reports

I have used Jasper reports in my desktop application,

as

```
    void showResports(){
    try{
      // OriginalExportOriginalExport 
         String reportName ="";
        //ExportReport4.jasperExportReport4.jasper
        if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
  reportName = "OriginalExport.jrxml";
        }
        else if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
         reportName = "ExportReport4.jrxml";

        }


   InputStream in =getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportName);

  if(in==null|| connection==null) return ;


   JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(in);
   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
   JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, connection);
  System.out.println("Object of Jasper Print created");

              JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);

     //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
            jf.validate();
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
            jf.setLocation(300,100);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);



  File f=new File(reportName);
  if(f.exists()) System.out.println("Yes Yes File is there");
  else 
  System.out.println("File is not there"+f.getAbsolutePath());


   }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();}

    }// showReports

 }
```

When check on console it says file not found , so i am worried why this error is occuring , though it works well in netebeans?

now i get

```
C:\Users\FFIS WIN03\dist\report32name_1338142442500_473143.java
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:89)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractClassCompiler.compileUnits(JRAbstractClassCompiler.java:63)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:188)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:212)
        at pos.ViewAllPayments$Reporter.showResports(ViewAllPayments.java:1339)
        at pos.ViewAllPayments.importButtonActionPerformed(ViewAllPayments.java:1098)
        at pos.ViewAllPayments.access$2100(ViewAllPayments.java:39)
        at pos.ViewAllPayments$20.actionPerformed(ViewAllPayments.java:448)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error= 2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:58)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 47 more
```

Comment: I got the same problem, have you found any result?

Answer (score 0):

That file does not exist in the classpath. Usually it is better in many cases to take the absolute path of the file from the command line. Otherwise, make sure that you have the location of the file in your classpath.

Comment: file is in the same class in which other classes are present

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the .jrxml file as resource, so you can read it with `getResourceAsStream` even from a jar file. But then you ought not use it as `File` in the file system. In fact that used the application startup directory, which even varies.

To detect the presence: `getResource` would return a null URL when not present. That should probably be done *before* `getResourceAsStream`.

The package of the class on which you use `getResourceAsStream` will be the starting path for relative paths. You might use absolute paths like "/org/jasperreports/samples/sample1.jrxml".

Comment: Sorry no experience with dynamic compilation to say something on the stack trace. Precompiled the reports. Try that, maybe something is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note is that `getResourceAsStream` extracts from your **classpath**, but `new File` is relative from your current directory.

If your class resources from Netbeans includes: `${currentdir}/build/classes`, and your jrxml file is there, then `getResourceAsStream` will succeed, but the `new File` will fail as ${currentdir}/OriginalExport.jrxml is not present.